# Expected task end date is not reflecting . Need help (Microsoft Project)

Tags: ms-project

> Scenario:
>
> A task, say "Paint the wall", requires total 24 hours to complete.
>
> For a day, we expect daily working hours for each person is 8 hours.

- The project needs to start by Wednesday. (i.e., 7 Jan 2015 in this video)
- 3 people were assigned to complete this task effectively.
- We expected 8 hours from each, hence we expected the work to be completed in one day!

But, we have the following constraints:

- 1st person "A" can work only for 4 hours daily.
- 2nd person "B" can also work only for 4 hours daily.
- 3rd person "C" can work only for 2 hours daily and also not available to work on Thursday and Friday.
- Saturday and Sunday are generally holiday and no work is expected.

With the above constraints, this 24 hours work can be completed by:

On Wednesday,

- People "A" and "B" will work for 4 hours each. Person "C" will work for 2 hours.
- Hence, 4+4+2 = 10 hours work should be completed.

On Thursday,

- People "A" and "B" will work for 4 hours each. Person "C" will not work.
- Hence, 4+4 = 8 hours work should be completed. (Total: 18 hours work completed so far. Remaining work expected is 6 hours)

On Friday,

- People "A" and "B" will work for 3 hours each. Person "C" will not work.
- Hence, 3+3 = 6 hours work should be completed. (Total: 24hours work completed by Friday. This is the expected output.)

But while trying the above scenario, Ms Project calculates differently and splits the work incorrectly to resources and shows that work will be completed by next Tuesday only! (i.e., 13 Jan 2015 in this video).

We need assistance how to fix this. Or on how to achieve the desired result in ms project.

The steps tried are shown in the video, which incorrectly calculates and shows the work will be completed by 13 Jan 2015 (Tuesday only).

This is the video on YouTube: [Project 2013 Case Study](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9fhXiejG7I)

Please suggest how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

To get what you want, you need to manually change the assigned work for resources A/B from 8 hours to 11 hours and for resource C from 8 hours to 2 hours.  You can do this with either the Task Usage or Resource Usage view on the bottom pane.

[image: MSP Resource Usage View]

Unlike what you expect, MSP will not treat three distinct resources as fully interchangeable commodities, allocating work among them for the shortest possible schedule.  That is the project manager’s job.

There is another tool – Spider Project – that incorporates skill-based resource scheduling.  You may consider that if your need is great.